# Returning derived object pointer from virtual method

Tags: c++, c++11

Why does s1->duplicate() not return a Box* in **code sample 1**? 
I would assume that the derived duplicate is called and as such that Box* is returned but it seems a Shape* is returned instead.

**Code Sample 1:**

```
#include <iostream>

struct Shape
{
  virtual Shape* duplicate()
  {
      std::cout << "c" << std::endl;
      return new Shape;
  }
  virtual void print()
  {
    std::cout << "SHAPE" << std::endl;
  }
  virtual ~Shape() {}
};

struct Box : public Shape
{
  virtual Box* duplicate()
  {
      std::cout << "b" << std::endl;
      return new Box;
  }
  virtual void print()
  {
    std::cout << "BOX" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
  Shape* s1 = new Box;
  Box* b1 = s1->duplicate();  //ISSUE HERE
  b1->print();

  delete s1;
  delete b1;
  return 0; 
}
```

Error:
34:27: error: invalid conversion from 'Shape*' to 'Box*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: `Why does s1->duplicate() not return a Box*` Well, probably because of this: `return new Shape;`

Comment: @DimChtz: It's virtual, the `return new Box;` is the line that's hit

Comment: Because it's calling a virtual function that returns `Shape *`, and not a `Box *`.

Comment: one returns a box* the other returns a shape*

Comment: What do you mean virtual function returns Shape*?  the code in the virtual function is "return new Box;".

Comment: virtual Box* duplicate() { ... return new Box;}  to be honest I'm surprised it even compiles.

Comment: I don't know who down voted this, but I bet they didn't understand the code and the question.  It's quite tricky.  The derived function is hit, virtual Box* duplicate() { ... return new Box;}... yet it does not return Box*...

Comment: You're calling `duplicate()` on a Shape*. The definition of duplicate() in the Shape class returns a Shape*. Yes, the object you have is really a Box, but since you've cast that to a Shape* the compiler only knows that it's allowed to use the duplicate() definition on Shape. (And, as a few other commenters have noted, it may not technically actually be allowed to assume duplicate() called on a Box* pointer returns a Box* anyway since you've changed the return type of a virtual.)

Comment: Rup, I don't think that is accurate.  I didn't cast to Shape and slice the object. I'm using a base ptr and polymorphically calling duplicate of Box.  To provide it, in main change Box* b1 = s1->duplicate(); to Shape* b1 = s1->duplicate(); and you'll see that s1->duplicate() is a polymorphic call to dupllicate() of Box.

Comment: Sid, is it not the case that while you can't overload a method unless params differ (you are right, ret val diff is not enough), you can override methods even if there is no diff in params or return val.  That's kind of the point of polymorphism is it not?

Comment: See this [tutorial](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/125-the-virtual-table/) to learn how things happen at deep level. Static vs dynamic binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ is "Invariant" not "contravariant" which means a pointer to base class can hold an object of the derived class but not the contrary.

So in your code:

```
Box* b1 = s1->duplicate();  //ISSUE HERE
```

Above you are trying to store in `b1` an object of the `shape` class. Which ii incorrect.

Your clone function is correct but you misuse it.

- I think you are not understanding correctly how `Polymorphism` is achieved and works.

  ```
  Shape* s1 = new Box; // s1 is of Type Shape whatever the type of object it point to be.
  Box* b1 = (Box*)s1->duplicate();
  b1->print();
  ```

Comment: Box* b = new Box is valid code.  s1->Duplicate() calls the version in Box, which returns new Box... so why can't I assign this new Box that is returned to Box* b1?

Comment: You are misunderstanding polymorphism. You can never assign a base pointer to a derived pointer whatever the value is stored in the base one Finish.

Comment: I know s1 is of type Box polymorphically, so it calls Box's duplicate method...which returns new Box.  Is this not the same as Box* b1 = new Box; ?

Comment: right, but what confuses me is that I'm not assigning a base ptr to a derived ptr as far as I can see.  I'm assigning a derived ptr to a derived ptr, no?

Comment: Yes it is not. It is ok to be known at runtime. But the problem is "Compile-time error" : trying to assign in unacceptable  types.

Comment: OK, but method called returns new Box.  So why can't this new Box be assigned to Box*?

Comment: you need to downcast the base pointer to derived class then assign.

Comment: Is the return value of s1-duplicate() not Box* if I don't down-cast s1?

Comment: @code The return value of `s1->duplicate()` is a `Shape *` because `s1` is a `Shape *`, the compile time type.  If `s1` would be a `Box *` then `s1->duplicate()` would be a `Box *`.

Comment: 1201ProgAlarm...ohhhh... i see.... so during compile time because s1 is Shape* the compiler wants to call Shape::duplicate() non-polymorphically which returns Shape*.... but this is FLASE... in fact wrong...and so during run time....Shape::duplicate() is not called...compiler is wrong...instead...Box::duplicate() is called polymorphically which returns Box*.... and even thow Box::duplicate() returned Box* and I'm trying to assign to Box* b1... the silly compiler thinks I'm trying to assign a Shape* to a Box*.  Is this explanation correct or am I still miss-understanding?

Comment: @code It calls the `duplicate()` in `Box`, since it is virtual function with a covariant return type, but the compiler doesn't know that `s1` is a `Box *`, since you've told it that it is only a `Shape *`.  So it only knows that `duplicate()` returns a `Shape *` (or a class derived from it).

Comment: Right, so polymorphism kicks in at run-time.  The compiler isn't smart enough to know that s1 is actually a Box...but at run-time... the program is smart enough to know that s1 is actually a Box...hence it calls Box::duplicate() not Shape::duplicate().  Right?

Comment: @code I wouldn't quite phrase it that way, but essentially Right.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `duplicate()` with a `Shape *` so the return value is `Shape *`.

Change this:

```
Box* b1 = s1->duplicate();
```

to:

```
Shape *b1 = s1->duplicate();
```

When you then run your program, you'll see that `b1` is indeed a `Box`.